# How to connect put request with axios to make it work on frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I wrote the put request which works perfectly, I want to connect it with axios to make it work on frontend with `onClick` method.

```
 router.put("/:name", (req, res, next) => {
Papp.findOneAndUpdate({ _pappName: req.params.pappName }, req.body, {
  new: true
 }).then(function(state) {
res.send(state);
 });
});
```

[image]

To make it more clear: Buttons get their state from database via the props. User can click button and change its state but only on frontend now, I want to change it so user will be able to change record in database because of the request.

Comment: Could you add a snippet of where in your current frontend the button is...??

Comment: Sure, its in client/src/Components/mainpage/Maintancebuttonpapp.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the syntax below:

```
axios.put(url[, data[, config]])
```

and program for example :

```html
 axios.put('http://127.0.0.1/myapp/public/api/bid/'+this.itemID,
          {
          NewBidMade:this.NewBidMade
          })
            .then((response) => {

              console.log(response.data);    
      
            })
            .catch(function(error){
              console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It clearly helped but now I have access problem

Comment: what's your mean by access problem?

Comment: Sure! Its: Access to XHTML Request has been blocked by CORS Policy: Response to preflight request doesnt pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I assume its about the 'authorization' and token, I did as @Sumit Kumar wrote in his answer but then it says that token is not defined

Comment: You need to provide token value on the place of 'your_token'.  If your server doesn't require authorization then remove authorization key from headers.

Comment: are u using nodejs as servider side technology.

Comment: if you are using nodejs then you need to install cors npm package and use app.use(cors()) like that on server side in server file.

Comment: Yes i do use nodejs, Im installing the corst npm package right now

Comment: Okey, it seems that server just got lagged as hell. It lets me make a put request but no changes though. Its more llike onClick GET request

Comment: have u used that middleware app.use(cors())

Comment: Yes I did use app.use(cors()). It seems like its more a problem with request, no matter which button I click it shows me that I click button from 1st record in database which is so wrong. It return me the url of 'api/papp/undefined' which I guess its wrong as well

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following.

```
axios.put(url,data, {
headers: {
    'authorization': your_token,
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
})
.then(response => {
// return  response;
})
.catch((error) => {
//return  error;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me with these headers in some way but I still have an access problem

Comment: Sure! Its: Access to XHTML Request has been blocked by CORS Policy: Response to preflight request doesnt pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: You need to implement cors policy in your server so then can allow your origin to access.

Comment: Sadly the problem is still the same :/

Comment: Sorry, cors works good, my server got extremely lagged, I have a problem with request now but I guess I have to figure it out by myself! Thank you guys for the help ! <3